# handleSubmit with Formik using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

I have successfully written a Login component in React using plain Javascript. I would now like to convert this component to TypeScript. I have defined some types and also threw in some "any" just to initially compile. Unfortunately, the onClick parameter in my submit button throws the following error:

*TS2322: Type '(e?: FormEvent | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>)
=> void'.*

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, LoginState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  async login(values) {
    const user = {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
    };

    const query = `mutation userLogin(
      $user: UserLoginInputs!
    ) {
      userLogin(
        user: $user
      ) {
        token
      }
    }`;

    const data: any = await graphQLFetch(query, { user });
    if (data && data.userLogin.token) {
      const decoded: any = jwt.decode(data.userLogin.token);
      const { onUserChange } = this.props;
      onUserChange({ loggedIn: true, givenName: decoded.givenName });
      const { history } = this.props;
      history.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        onSubmit={this.login}
        validationSchema={loginSchema}
        initialValues={{
          email: '',
          password: '',
        }}
      >
        {({
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange,
          values,
        }) => (
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <Form>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>E-mail</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    name="email"
                    value={values.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    name="password"
                    value={values.password}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form>
              <Button
                type="button"
                variant="primary"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new to TypeScript and don't fully understand why an error occurs regarding *e* versus *event* when the login function does not explicitly reference either of those. Can someone please help me assign types to my handleSubmit function (aka login)?

Comment: Does this blog -> https://formik.org/docs/guides/typescript solve your problem?

Comment: The key here seems to be using the Form and Field options from the Formik module, while I was trying to use the Form option from React Bootstrap. This works at the cost of now needing to learn how to style the input box. Thank you, @PrateekThapa!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that example could help you to resolve your issue

```js
import { Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

interface MyFormValues {
  firstName: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const initialValues: MyFormValues = { firstName: '' };

  const getSubmitHandler =
    () =>
    (values, formik) => {
      console.log({ values, formik });
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      formik.setSubmitting(false);
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={getSubmitHandler()}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
            <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={(event) =>
                getSubmitHandler()(formik.values, formik)
              }
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).